# How to use BIRT chart in PHP

Tags: java, php, charts, birt

How do I use BIRT chart to show a chart representation, like bar chart and pie chart, using PHP?
Can someone help me, or point to a tutorial?

I am using this reference: http://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/usingPHP.php

Comment: As I understand it, you're trying this and it's not working. Could you explain what is going wrong?

Comment: i m just trying to learn birt chart so that i can implement in php has  frontend so what will be  a better way 2 use birt chart i was asking ,

Comment: i dont know java at all only php :(

Comment: You can't implement directly a BIRT view in your php page. You have to set up a Tomcat server and redirect like in the example : $dest = "http://localhost:8080/birt-viewer/run?__report=[your_blabla_report_here]";
It will open a "Birt-Viewer" and you'll see the report here.

Comment: hi but i cant use tomcat server my domain doesnt support it any other way of integrating it with php for reporting with apache help .

Comment: i had used  this tutorial and ran a sample birt report too but disappoint too find that i cant use tomcat which is very imp any other way my friend please it urgent or commecial method   http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363642/Intergrating-BIRT-with-PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Reportico PHP Report Designer. It is not as versatile as Birt but still I think it will be helpful

Comment: actually am looking for a chart tool that gives drill down reporting feature and i am instructed to look in to birt  report .